# Using Python, how can I get the text of an XML element when a sibling element's tag is the string I am looking for?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, parent-child, elementtree

I hope this is an easy question.  I will try to be clear on what I am trying to accomplish.  Below is just a small snippet of what my XML file looks like.  What I am trying to do is see if the  element structure exists.  If so, the code proceeds.  I then try to look through all of the  elements and if child element (test) is False, then I would like to get the text of the id element.  The following code I have will work if the  element is before the  element.  I want to make sure that whatever order ID is list in (before or after the ) that I get the appropriate child id belonging to the appropriate  parent.  Currently I am using element tree.

```
<data>
<cs>
    <c>
        <id>1</id>
        <test>True</test>
        <test2>False</test2>
        <test3>False</test3>
        <test4>True</test4>
    </c>
    <c>
        <test>False</test>
        <test2>False</test2>
        <test3>False</test3>
        <id>2</id>
        <test4>True</test4>
    </c>
</cs>
```

```
elementTree = self.param2
isCS = elementTree.find('./cs')
getCS = elementTree.findall('./cs')
CIDs = []

if isCS is None:
    raise Exception("Unable to find the 'cs' element structure under <data>. Failed to build a list of CID's.")
else:
    # Build the list of CID's.
    for cs in getCS:
        for c in cs:
            for child in c.getchildren():
                if str(child.tag).lower() == 'id':
                    myid = child.text
                elif str(child.tag).lower() == 'test' and str(child.text).lower() == 'false':
                    CIDs.append(myid)

    print CIDs
```

What I am getting (depending on the order which the  element is listed) is the following output:

1

When I am really expecting the following:

2

I just need to know how I can run specific tests on the subelements of  and get data depending on what I find in the text of .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
cids = []
for c_node in tree.findall('.//cs/c'):
    test_node = c_node.find('test')
    if test_node is not None and test_node.text == 'False':
        id_node = c_node.find('id')
        cids.append(id_node.text)

print cids
```

## Discussion

- In the `for` loop, I locate all the **c** nodes under **cs**
- Next, I checked to see if the "test" node exist and is *False*
- Finally, I append the **id** to the list

Comment: Excellent!  Works great.  Thank you for taking the time to provide such a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested.

```
# Build the list of CID's.
for cs in getCS:
    for c in cs:
        myid = None
        mytest = None
        for child in c.getchildren():
            if str(child.tag).lower() == 'id':
                myid = child.text
            elif str(child.tag).lower() == 'test' and str(child.text).lower() == 'false':
                mytest = True
        if myid and mytest:
            CIDs.append(myid)

print CIDs
```

Probably it can be done in different way - using some special function or `find()`, `findall()` on `c` element.

---

EDIT:

Example with `lxml` (it is only example so it is no "bulletproof")

```
import lxml.etree

xml = '''<data>
<cs>
    <c>
        <id>1</id>
        <test>True</test>
        <test2>False</test2>
        <test3>False</test3>
        <test4>True</test4>
    </c>
    <c>
        <test>False</test>
        <test2>False</test2>
        <test3>False</test3>
        <id>2</id>
        <test4>True</test4>
    </c>
</cs>
</data>'''

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)

all_c = tree.findall('./cs/c')

#print all_c

results = []

for c in all_c:
    #print c

    myid = c.find('id').text
    mytest = (c.find('test').text.lower() == 'false')

    print myid, mytest

    if myid and mytest: 
        results.append(myid)

print "results:", results
```

Comment: Thanks you for the response.  I ended up coming up with the same answer, so that is kind of funny.  If anyone knows a way to do it with find() or findall() I am all ears for a better method.  It is working right now and I appreicate the repsonse!

Comment: I add example with `find()` and `findall()` using `lxml`